# JNDI spring embedded tomcat : maven multi module project

Tags: spring, maven, jndi, multi-module, maven-tomcat-plugin

I still cant get this thing in my head :

this is how my project looks :

```
--app
--app-core     (spring)
--app-model    (pojo)
--app-service  (jersey)  >> final package as war  (dependencies (appcore+appmodel))
```

Now here where should my applicationContext.xml sits ????
Dependencies of Spring goes to only app-core ???? ...

**UPDATE**

app-core     (spring) has applicationContext.xml, Know I would like to use JNDI with embedded tomcat (tomcat-maven-plugin).

Have  created `context.xml`  inside webapp/META-INF it looks like :-

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context docBase="nweb" path="/nweb" reloadable="true">  
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>  
<Resource name="jdbc/TestDS" auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        driverClass="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=TestData"
        username="sa" password=""/>     
  </Context>
```

..

my applicationContext.xml : -

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:/TestDS"></property>
</bean>     
 </beans>
```

with the above I get this below error :

```
   at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
   Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name TestDSis not bound in this 
    Context
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:770)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:152)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
    at
```

Any suggestions if am missing out anything ?

Answer (score 2):

Typically you would configure a ContextLoaderListener on your web.xml for your root application context:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This class uses the param value contextConfigLocation -- from which you can explicitly specify where your applicationContext.xml should be:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: ok have done few changes ..could you please check my updated qn ?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <contextFile>webapp/META-INF/context.xml</contextFile>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

try `<property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/TestDS"></property>`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using embedded tomcat 7 then you should call

```
tomcat.enableNaming();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an application working with JNDI [here](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/bees-shop-clickstart). I have been using JNDI on a PaaS where they explain how to do the binding between your app and the db. You can have more details on this [tutorial](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Springframework).

Basically you need to put this on your datasource.xml file:

```
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/mydb" resource-ref="true"
   expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

Then, on your Tomcat server, you have several possibilities as you can see on the Spring tutorial I put the link. Easiest way is going to $CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml and put something like this.

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" minIdle="1" name="jdbc/mydb" password="dbUserPassword" testOnBorrow="true" testWhileIdle="true" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName" username="dbUserName" validationInterval="5000" validationQuery="select 1"/>
```